# How to view backtrace of untracked stack

Tags: gdb, cortex-m

Using arm-none-eabi-gdb, Cortex M0, FreeRTOS.

How can I view stack trace of an arbitrary stack at address `addr`?

Do I have to manually change the stack pointer, or is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 0):

Just view the memory in the debugger, remembering the stack grows downwards.

Comment: It's not so immediate.

Comment: Yes, of course, but I wanted to have gdb analyze the frames and determine local variables, function calls, etc in the nice visual representation that it normally does. I see that gdb can do a backtrace of different threads, but it doesn't recognize my FreeRTOS tasks and threads.